# Columns must be same length as key error pandas dataframe problem

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, key, row

I keep getting the "Columns must be same length as key" error. No idea why

here is my code for when I am changing up the pandas data frame...

```
sdf = pd.DataFrame(list(shots.items()),columns = ['Coordinates', 'Occurences (S, G)'])
#sdf['Percentage']=sdf['Occurences (S, G)'].apply( lambda x: x[1]/x[0])
sdf[['S','G']] = pd.DataFrame(sdf['Occurences (S, G)'].tolist(), index=sdf.index)   
sdf[['X-','Y']] = pd.DataFrame(sdf['Coordinates'].tolist(), index=sdf.index)
sdf['Shot Percentage'] = sdf['G'] / sdf['S']
sdf = sdf.drop(['Coordinates', 'Occurences (S, G)'], axis = 1)
sdf['X'] = abs(sdf['X-'])
sdf = sdf.drop(['X-'], axis = 1)
sdf = sdf[["X", "Y", "S", "G", "Shot Percentage"]]
```

Here's a sample of the data I am searching through....

```
}, {
        "players" : [ {
          "player" : {
            "id" : 8476948,
            "fullName" : "Charles Hudon",
            "link" : "/api/v1/people/8476948"
          },
          "playerType" : "Shooter"
        }, {
          "player" : {
            "id" : 8475883,
            "fullName" : "Frederik Andersen",
            "link" : "/api/v1/people/8475883"
          },
          "playerType" : "Goalie"
        } ],
        "result" : {
          "event" : "Shot",
          "eventCode" : "TOR206",
          "eventTypeId" : "SHOT",
          "description" : "Charles Hudon Wrap-around saved by Frederik Andersen",
          "secondaryType" : "Wrap-around"
        },
        "about" : {
          "eventIdx" : 76,
          "eventId" : 206,
          "period" : 1,
          "periodType" : "REGULAR",
          "ordinalNum" : "1st",
          "periodTime" : "14:43",
          "periodTimeRemaining" : "05:17",
          "dateTime" : "2018-10-03T23:42:53Z",
          "goals" : {
            "away" : 1,
            "home" : 1
          }
```

Let me know if you know the fix
Thanks!

Comment: Could you share a small sample of the data the code is supposed to work on?

Comment: yea, I'll edit the question